# strings and textfields, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**How do I get my text fields to populate correctly and show single digits?**

**Description**
Each textfield receives a substring. This doesn't limit it's input, because the text fields shows extra numbers. See illustration.

**Ex A**

```
//Tweening method 'could substitute code with Tweener'
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
//Timer that will run a sec and repeat
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
//Integer values
var count:int = +220000000;
var fcount:int = 0;
//Events and starting timer
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkOdometerPosition);
timer.start();
//Tween Variables
var smoothLoop:int = 0;
var originalYPosition:Number = 0;
var upwardYPosition:Number = -99;
//Formatting String
function formatCount(i:int):String { 
var fraction:int = i % 100; 
var whole:int = i / 100;  
return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
} 
//First Digit 'trigger set by using var upwardPosition as a constant'
function checkOdometerPosition(event:Event):void{
if (seconds9.y <= upwardYPosition){
var toText:String = formatCount(fcount);
//seconds9.firstDigit.text = formatCount(fcount);
seconds9.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(9, 9);
seconds9.y = originalYPosition;
seconds8.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(8, 8);
seconds8.y = originalYPosition;
seconds7dec.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(7, 7);
seconds7dec.y = originalYPosition;
seconds6.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(6, 6);
seconds6.y = originalYPosition;
seconds5.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(5, 5);
seconds5.y = originalYPosition;
seconds5.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(4, 4);
seconds5.y = originalYPosition;
seconds3.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(3, 3);
seconds3.y = originalYPosition;
seconds2.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(2, 2);
seconds2.y = originalYPosition;
seconds1.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(1, 1);
seconds1.y = originalYPosition;
seconds1.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(1, 1);
seconds1.y = originalYPosition;
seconds0.firstDigit.text = toText.substr(0, 1);
seconds0.y = originalYPosition;
}
}
//Second Digit
function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent):void{
count++;  
fcount=int(count)
if (smoothLoop < 9){
smoothLoop++;
}
else {
smoothLoop = 0;
}
var lolly:String = formatCount(fcount-1);
//seconds9.secondDigit.text = formatCount(fcount);
seconds9.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(9, 9);
var addTween9:Tween = new Tween(seconds9, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds8.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(8, 8);
var addTween8:Tween = new Tween(seconds8, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds7dec.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(7, 7);
var addTween7dec:Tween = new Tween(seconds7dec, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds6.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(6, 6);
var addTween6:Tween = new Tween(seconds6, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds5.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(5, 5);
var addTween5:Tween = new Tween(seconds5, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds4.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(4, 4);
var addTween4:Tween = new Tween(seconds4, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds3.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(3, 3);
var addTween3:Tween = new Tween(seconds3, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds2.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(2, 2);
var addTween2:Tween = new Tween(seconds2, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds1.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(1, 1);
var addTween1:Tween = new Tween(seconds1, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
seconds0.secondDigit.text = lolly.substr(0, 1);
var addTween0:Tween = new Tween(seconds0, "y", Strong.easeOut,0,-222, .7, true);
}
```

**Ex A** has 10 text objects, each with a pair of text fields. 
It’s move complex than Ex B, because it has a Y animation and pairs of
numbers. The text objects are animated to create a scrolling effect. It moves vertically, and has a lead number and a catch up number contained in each symbol. See illustration for more description.

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/noob___.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/noob___.jpg)
[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/noob__.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/noob__.jpg)

The counters are set to 2,200,000.00, just to see if the numbers are populating.

**Ex B** work fine! for example only

```
//STRING SPLITTER COUNTER with nine individual text fields
//Timer settings
var delay:uint = 1000/100;
var repeat:uint = 0; 
var timer:Timer;
timer = new Timer(delay,repeat);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);
timer.start();
//Integer values
var count:int = 0;
var fcount:int = 0; 
//Format Count
function formatCount(i:int):String { 
var fraction:int = i % 100; 
var whole:int = i / 100;  
return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
} 
//Split strings off to individual text fields
function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
count++;  
fcount=int(count+220000000)
var toText:String = formatCount(fcount);
mytext9.text = toText.substr(9, 9);
mytext8.text = toText.substr(8, 8);
mytext7dec.text = toText.substr(7, 7);
mytext6.text = toText.substr(6, 6);
mytext5.text = toText.substr(5, 5);
mytext4.text = toText.substr(4, 4);
mytext3.text = toText.substr(3, 3);
mytext2.text = toText.substr(2, 2);
mytext1.text = toText.substr(1, 1);
mytext0.text = toText.substr(0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only had a chance to quickly look over your code, but I guess that you might be using substr() incorrectly. I think I understand correctly, that you want to get one digit in each box, from a long number stored in a String object. If so, the way that substr works is as follows:

substr(letter to start at, number of letters to go after that);

So you see, if you have a String of 10 digits (say, 1234567890), and you do thatString.substr(3,3), it'll return 456, because you're starting at index 3 (and there's a 0 index too), and you're including 3 digits after that starting index. So if you want just single digits out of your substr, you need to do just (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), etc.

I hope this makes sense, and fixes the problem.

debu

Comment: @debu, That will do. The substr works as you described it. Without including the zeros, it was throwing it off. The flip, led, or odometer should all work the same way now. Thanks.

Comment: @debu, I had a dumb moment:) My top row of numbers was not moving because the ceiling set with originalYPosition. I haven't found the sweet spot with the tweening either, but it's showing promise.